# Mixing single and double quotes in the R paste function?

Tags: mysql, r, paste, double-quotes, rmysql

This seems ridiculous, but I just can't get this right - any help much appreciated please!

Basically: I'm using RMySQL to do some simple SQL, in order to get my head around how SQL works. I'd like to chain together a few SQL `select` queries, as a simple example. This is covered in the RMySQL PDF - but the example therein seems to be the incorrect syntax (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf , page 3, example 6).

If I have three queries, say like this:

```
q1 <- "SELECT db.table FROM table WHERE stuff = 'blah' "
q2 <- "SELECT db.other_table FROM other_table WHERE stuff = 'different blah' "
q3 <- "SELECT db.table2 FROM table2 WHERE table2 = 1000"
```

and try to `paste` them as follows:

```
script <- paste(q1, q2, q3, sep=";")
```

the result is

```
> script
[1] "SELECT db.table FROM table WHERE stuff = 'blah' ;SELECT fb.other_table FROM
other_table WHERE stuff = 'different blah' ;SELECT db.table2 FROM table2 WHERE table2 =
'1000'
```

and so invoking `dbSendQuery` clearly fails.

I've tried `\"`, but this also doesn't work:

```
q1 <- "SELECT db.table FROM table WHERE stuff = 'blah' \" "
q2 <- "SELECT db.other_table FROM other_table WHERE stuff = 'different blah' \""
q3 <- "SELECT db.table2 FROM table2 WHERE table2 = 1000 \" "

script <- paste(q1, q2, q3, sep=";")

> script
[1] "SELECT db.table FROM table WHERE stuff = 'blah' \" ;  ;SELECT db.other_table FROM
other_table WHERE stuff = 'different blah' \";SELECT db.table2 FROM table2 WHERE table2
= 1000 \" "
```

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: just for clarification, executing this via RMySQL as follows:

```
my.queries <- dbGetQuery(my.con, script, client.flag = CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)
```

as per the RMySQL manual, I get

```
RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Presumably, this is because the result of the `paste` function should be:

```
"SELECT db.table FROM table WHERE stuff = 'blah'" ;"SELECT fb.other_table FROM
other_table WHERE stuff = 'different blah'" ;"SELECT db.table2 FROM table2 WHERE table2
= '1000'"
```

Each of the individual queries works just fine, so I'm assuming that it's my `paste` command that's causing the issue.

EDIT: to simplify this: suppose I have two strings, as follows:

```
t1 <- "the 'stuff'"
t2 <- "more 'stuff'"
paste(t1, t2, sep=";")
[1] "the 'stuff' ; more 'stuff' "
```

what I'd like is for the result of the paste command to be `"the 'stuff'";"more 'stuff'"`.

Comment: You first approach appears to be correct. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks Sven, have added some clarification.

Comment: Did you use `dbConnection` with the argument `client.flag = CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`?

Comment: Well, that's embarassing.... I put the `client.flag = CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` in the `dbGetQuery` call... Many thanks for sorting out my stupidity, Sven!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the argument `client.flag = CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` to the function `dbConnection`, not to `dgGetQuery`.

Then, your first approach should work:

```
q1 <- "SELECT db.table FROM table WHERE stuff = 'blah' "
q2 <- "SELECT db.other_table FROM other_table WHERE stuff = 'different blah' "
q3 <- "SELECT db.table2 FROM table2 WHERE table2 = 1000"

script <- paste(q1, q2, q3, sep=";")
```